# portaudio pa_devs report 0 device

Tags: portaudio

My system is ubuntu 15.10. I am very sure my audio works,

```
arecord -l

**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC887-VD Alt Analog [ALC887-VD Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

but pa_devs, which is a official provided execuatble file in portaudio, reports 0 device as below,

```
PortAudio version number = 1899
PortAudio version text = 'PortAudio V19-devel (built Jan 30 2016 19:22:45)'
Number of devices = 0
```

And I can get devices number with pyAudio

```
import pyaudio

pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
print(pa.get_default_input_device_info())
print(pa.get_device_count())

--- output ---

{'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'maxInputChannels': 32, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.008707482993197279, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.008707482993197279, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0, 'hostApi': 0, 'structVersion': 2, 'maxOutputChannels': 32, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'name': 'default', 'index': 6}
7
```

Should I install something or re-built portaudio with some special settings? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this exact same problem. It was because `portaudio` was built with only support for OSS. You need to build it with ALSA support. Note that even if you specify `--with-alsa` to the `./configure` script it still "succeeds" even if it can't find ALSA - you have to manually check the configuration summary for a line like this:

```
 ALSA ........................ no
```

(Don't you love autotools?)

Anyway do this:

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev
./configure
```

And so on. I unfortunately couldn't find a way to get `pa_devs` to list what backends it supports, so you just have to guess this is the problem and try it. Worked for me anyway!

Comment: After try&error, I had solved it after installing alsa. Thanks anyway, it will help who runs into the problem!